# Trigger Specific value into different database

Tags: sql, triggers

i am new to trigger, is there a way to trigger input to databaseB.track conferenceid whenever there is a new record in databaseA.conference? this is what i did and is not working.

```
DELIMITER//
CREATE or replace TRIGGER insert_confer
after insert ON conference
for each row
begin 
insertdatabaseb.Track(:new.conferenceid);
end;
/

                    DatabaseA                     Database B
                    Conference                    Track
                   -conferenceid                 -Trackid
                   -conferencename               -Trackname
                   -conferencevenue              -Conferenceid
```

Comment: Tag dbms used! (That code is product specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't the trigger *per se* but rather the syntax on the `insert`.  Perhaps:

```
DELIMITER//
CREATE or replace TRIGGER insert_confer
after insert ON conference
for each row
begin 
    insert into databaseb.Track(conferenceid)
        values (:new.conferenceid);
end//
DELIMITER ;
```